# onblur event to trigger alert. Total noob

Tags: javascript, html

Appologize if this has been answered. Pretty fresh so should be fairly easy. I can't get this event to work and I'm not should where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

**My html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Final Project</title>
    <script src="courseproject.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Type a number in the box below, choose either 1, 2, or 3.</p>
    <input type="text" id="nbr" onblur="myFunction()">
</body>

<footer style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px">
    <a href="main.html" class="menu">Home</a> 
    <a href="aboutme.html" class="menu">About</a> 
    <a href="futuregoals.html" class="menu">Goals</a> 
    <a href="contact.html" class="menu">Contact</a>
</footer>
</html>
```

**My external JS function:**

```
funciton myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("nbr").value;
    if (x == "1") {
        alert("Solid Choice");
    } else if (x == "2") {
        alert("Not Bad");
    } else if (x == "3") {
        alert("Eh You Tried");
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a typo in your function declaration, it is `function` not `funciton`

Comment: I accidentally mistyped that in my question. It is correct in the file and still doesn't run.

Comment: You nearly typed funkytown :)

Comment: Can you try moving the function into the HTML inside an `<script>` tag, just to make sure it's not something to do with the external file. Also is the `course project.js` file definitely at the same file level as the html page?

Comment: I tried that using the W3 schools try it editor and nothing.

Comment: @Beenjammin, move <script src="courseproject.js"></script> from head to html tag .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything was correct. It was suggested I use the inspect tool on firefox and look at the console log and sources. Turns out my FTP server wasn't taking the file I modified for some reason. Recreated, renamed and pushed again.

Answer (score 0):

Expose `myFunction` to `window` :

```js
window.myFunction = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nbr").value;
  if (x=="1") {
    alert("Solid Choice");
  } else if (x=="2") {
    alert("Not Bad");
  } else if (x=="3") {
    alert("Eh You Tried");
  }
}
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-bartik-h63x9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `function` in:

```
funciton myFunction() {
```

It happens to the best of us. Other than that, this code WORKS. I copied it and tested it. If it' not working for you, make sure your js path actually leads to your js file in the line:

```
<script src="courseproject.js"></script>
```

It should be in the same folder as your HTML file, and capitalization/extensions are important. If that's still not it, something is going wrong with some other code you're not showing us. Run this HTML file, right click the page, click "inspect", and then select the "Console" tab to see if you can find an error explanation there.